# Get result value from intent in terminal

Tags: android, adb

I'm working on a simple app that have a couple of intent services and no GUI. It works well and I can have services for things like enable/disable bluetooth/wifi through the terminal and adb.

But I wonder if there is any way (don't have to be intent services) to get a return value? For example say that I want to write something like this:

```
adb shell am startservice -n com.stuff.myService/.BluetoothStatus
```

Add it returns 1 or 0 to the terminal window. It's just an example and I guess you can't (or should) use services like that. But as I'm new to android development I'm looking for a concept that let me get settings and values in the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either implement a method returning a value in your service which you will call with `service call` command or you can print the value into the log and then parse the `logcat` output for the result.

Comment: Thanks! I liked the logcat idea and think it will work.